# Javascript/Jquery hiding all h2 on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I hide all the `h2` content in a page when mouse is not over that area, and only show on mouseover/hover in javascript or CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".redsquarecss")
  .hover(function() {
      $(".headers").show();
    },
    function() {
      $(".headers").hide()
    }
  );
```

```css
div.redsquarecss {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
div.headers {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="redsquarecss" title="Square 1"></div>
<div class="headers">
  <h2>This is heading 2</h2>
  <h2>This is heading 2</h2>
  <h2>This is heading 2</h2>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0r59so8r/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just hide all h2 to elements on start and show it on hover. You will need a trigger for the hover event, you mentioned it as "that area".

There are several approaches to achieve this:

- set the css display property to none `h2 {display:none}`
- set html [hidden property](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp) to true `<h2 hidden></h2>`
- or even css opacity to 0 `h2 {opacity:0}`(won't work using jquery `show()`)
- or trigger it via jquery on startup (more like dirty solution) `$('h2').hide()`

The jquery methods you are searching for are [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and `hide()`, you can also play around with animations using [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) functionality.

Have a look at:
https://jsfiddle.net/5caeLcn0/1/